# Getting external news articles thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a way to get the the thumbnail image from different news articles of major publishers (CNBC, Bloomberg, etc.)

Basically, I would want to provide an article url and in return to get the url of the article's thumbnail

any ideas?

Comment: When you say thumbnail, are you just talking about an image attached to an article, or screenshot of an article?

Comment: Well, you might want to parse the sites. Is it a fixed number of sites? Can you create a limit amount of parsers? Or it is not?

Comment: @dmtri.com not a screenshot. e.g. when you put a url of an article in a facebook post, it displays its thumbnail image, thats what im interested in

Answer (score 2):

found the right tool for the job: https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer

Comment: I just released a new version of the gem, it is now even faster and removes RMagick dependency :)